# Windows: Cassandra Multinode cluster VerifyPortsAreAvailable : Found a port already in use

Tags: windows, powershell, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to set up multinode(2) Cassandra cluster on single Windows machine. I have changed all the necessary properties in cassandra.yaml file specific to each node. But when I am starting my second node I am getting port already in use. I am not sure which port it is referring and what to change in my second node that will not use the same port which my first node is using.

I am using cassandra 2.2.6

```
    VerifyPortsAreAvailable : Found a port already in use.
    Aborting startup
    At C:\Users\Dell\BLAZENT\tools\multinode-cassandra\node2 \bin\cassandra.ps1:98 char:9
    +         VerifyPortsAreAvailable
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-
       Error], WriteErrorException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
       ands.WriteErrorException,VerifyPortsAreAvailable

    VerifyPortsAreAvailable :   TCP    127.0.0.1:7000
      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
    At C:\Users\Dell\BLAZENT\tools\multinode-cassandra\node2 \bin\cassandra.ps1:98 char:9
    +         VerifyPortsAreAvailable
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-
       Error], WriteErrorException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
       ands.WriteErrorException,VerifyPortsAreAvailable
```

This is my cassandra.bat file --

```html
@REM
@REM  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
@REM  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
@REM  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
@REM  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
@REM  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
@REM  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
@REM
@REM      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
@REM
@REM  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
@REM  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
@REM  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
@REM  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
@REM  limitations under the License.

@echo off
if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

set ARG=%1
set INSTALL="INSTALL"
set UNINSTALL="UNINSTALL"

pushd %~dp0..
if NOT DEFINED CASSANDRA_HOME set CASSANDRA_HOME=%CD%
popd

if /i "%ARG%" == "LEGACY" goto runLegacy
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM See if we have access to run unsigned powershell scripts
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('powershell Get-ExecutionPolicy') do set PERMISSION=%%i
if "%PERMISSION%" == "Unrestricted" goto runPowerShell
goto runLegacy

REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:runPowerShell
echo Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
set errorlevel=
powershell /file "%CASSANDRA_HOME%\bin\cassandra.ps1" %*
exit /b %errorlevel%

REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:runLegacy
echo WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
echo    Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
echo    on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
echo    functionality on this platform.

echo Starting with legacy startup options

if NOT DEFINED CASSANDRA_MAIN set CASSANDRA_MAIN=org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
if NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME goto :err

REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM JVM Opts we'll use in legacy run or installation
set JAVA_OPTS=-ea^
 -javaagent:"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar"^
 -Xms2G^
 -Xmx2G^
 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError^
 -XX:+UseParNewGC^
 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC^
 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled^
 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8^
 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1^
 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75^
 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly^
 -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml^
 -Djava.library.path="%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\sigar-bin"^
 -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199
REM **** JMX REMOTE ACCESS SETTINGS SEE: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/JmxSecurity ***
REM -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199^
REM -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false^
REM -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true^
REM -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\jmxremote.password

REM ***** CLASSPATH library setting *****
REM Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup
set CLASSPATH="%CASSANDRA_HOME%\conf"

REM For each jar in the CASSANDRA_HOME lib directory call append to build the CLASSPATH variable.
for %%i in ("%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\*.jar") do call :append "%%i"
goto okClasspath

:append
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%1
goto :eof

REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:okClasspath

REM JSR223 - collect all JSR223 engines' jars
for /D %%P in ("%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jsr223\*.*") do (
 for %%i in ("%%P\*.jar") do call :append "%%i"
)

REM JSR223/JRuby - set ruby lib directory
if EXIST "%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jsr223\jruby\ruby" (
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% "-Djruby.lib=%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jsr223\jruby"
)
REM JSR223/JRuby - set ruby JNI libraries root directory
if EXIST "%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jsr223\jruby\jni" (
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% "-Djffi.boot.library.path=%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jsr223\jruby\jni"
)
REM JSR223/Jython - set python.home system property
if EXIST "%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jsr223\jython\jython.jar" (
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% "-Dpython.home=%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jsr223\jython"
)
REM JSR223/Scala - necessary system property
if EXIST "%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jsr223\scala\scala-compiler.jar" (
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% "-Dscala.usejavacp=true"
)

REM Include the build\classes\main directory so it works in development
set CASSANDRA_CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\build\classes\main";"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\build\classes\thrift"
set CASSANDRA_PARAMS=-Dcassandra -Dcassandra-foreground=yes
set CASSANDRA_PARAMS=%CASSANDRA_PARAMS% -Dcassandra.logdir="%CASSANDRA_HOME%\logs"
set CASSANDRA_PARAMS=%CASSANDRA_PARAMS% -Dcassandra.storagedir="%CASSANDRA_HOME%\data"

if /i "%ARG%" == "INSTALL" goto doInstallOperation
if /i "%ARG%" == "UNINSTALL" goto doInstallOperation

echo Starting Cassandra Server
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OPTS% %CASSANDRA_PARAMS% -cp %CASSANDRA_CLASSPATH% "%CASSANDRA_MAIN%"
goto finally

REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:doInstallOperation
set SERVICE_JVM="cassandra"
rem location of Prunsrv
set PATH_PRUNSRV=%CASSANDRA_HOME%\bin\daemon\
set PR_LOGPATH=%PATH_PRUNSRV%

rem Allow prunsrv to be overridden
if "%PRUNSRV%" == "" set PRUNSRV=%PATH_PRUNSRV%prunsrv

echo trying to delete service if it has been created already
"%PRUNSRV%" //DS//%SERVICE_JVM%
rem quit if we're just going to uninstall
if /i "%ARG%" == "UNINSTALL" goto finally

echo Installing %SERVICE_JVM%. If you get registry warnings, re-run as an Administrator
"%PRUNSRV%" //IS//%SERVICE_JVM%

echo Setting startup parameters for %SERVICE_JVM%
set cmd="%PRUNSRV%" //US//%SERVICE_JVM% ^
 --Jvm=auto --StdOutput auto --StdError auto ^
 --Classpath=%CASSANDRA_CLASSPATH% ^
 --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=%CASSANDRA_MAIN% --StartMethod=main ^
 --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=%CASSANDRA_MAIN%  --StopMethod=stop

REM convert ' -' into ';-' so we can tokenize on semicolon as we may have spaces in folder names
set tempOptions=%JAVA_OPTS: -=;-%
REM Append the JAVA_OPTS, each with independent ++JvmOptions as delimited list fails for some options
:optStrip
for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in ("%tempOptions%") do (
    set JVMOPTIONS=%JVMOPTIONS% ++JvmOptions=%%a
    set tempOptions=%%b
)
if defined tempOptions goto :optStrip

REM do the same for CASSANDRA_PARAMS
set tempOptions=%CASSANDRA_PARAMS: -=;-%

:paramStrip
for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in ("%tempOptions%") do (
    set JVMOPTIONS=%JVMOPTIONS% ++JvmOptions=%%a
    set tempOptions=%%b
)
if defined tempOptions goto :paramStrip

%cmd% %JVMOPTIONS%

echo Installation of %SERVICE_JVM% is complete
goto finally

:err
echo JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set!
pause

REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:finally

ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the TCPView from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437

Open the TCPView application and sort the output by Port
Click on the record which points to Port 8888 and port 7199
Right click and "End Process"
Now, run the Cassandra.bat.